# Wiring a float switch for 220 septic pump

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a 120 volt septic pump with a 240 volt pump controlled by a float switch. How does the float get wired in to shut both legs of the 240 off when the pump is not running? I will be direct wiring it. Pump comes with float already.

Comment: Should have instructions and a wiring diagram on how to connect it. If not then you need to contact the manufacturer. Float switch probably already connected to the pump wiring.

Comment: Are you trying to use your old float switch. If so, it probably can’t do it. You’d need a new, double-pole float switch.

Comment: New pump comes with a float.

Comment: @Zach what make and model of float switch are you trying to wire up?

Comment: Its a champion CPSE single phase 240 volt septic pump.

Comment: It doesn't need to.  Shutting off both poles only needs to be done for safety disconnects, not for ordinary use.   Typical electric heating thermostats only interrupt one phase; the "2-pole" varieties only interrupt the other phase when you turn the knob all the way off.

Comment: Is the float attached to the pump or is it meant to be plugged inline?

Comment: So it is ok to wire the float in series with one of the hots and leave the other line connected straight to the pump? This is not going to cause damage to the pump or cause a fire hazard?